# Which part of this transistor model op amp represents pin 5?

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, bjt, oscillator

In this op amp oscillator pin 5 is connected to an RC circuit:

[image]

I have a transistor model of that op amp and I want to connect an RC circuit to it like the above circuit:

[image]

Since pin 4 and 8 represents the voltage source of that ideal op amp, I am not sure that I should connect that RC circuit like this:

[image]

Which part of the transistor model op amp represents pin 5?

Comment: I think the wiper of RV1, and the middle of R3 and R2, are the op-amp inputs

Comment: Your transistor model isn't really what I'd call an op amp. It's a long-tailed pair, sure, but that's just the *input* stage of an op amp. Even the venerable K2-W had additional amplification stages afterward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your op-amp oscillator is incorrectly drawn: -

[image]

You have the inputs swapped and it will no-longer behave like a relaxation oscillator. Regarding which pins are represented in your transistor circuit: -

[image]

But, it won't behave very well as a relaxation oscillator because the output node should be buffered and have a lower impedance output such that it can adequately drive the feedback components in the oscillator without gain or DC offset being unduly affected.